# python:confusion about assignment statement:l = [a,b] = [0,1]?

Tags: python

In python 3.4 interactive prompt:

```
    >>> l = [a,b] = [0,1]
    >>> a is l[0]
    True
    >>> b is l[1]
    True
    >>> l[0] = 2  
    >>> a
    0
    >>> l
    [2, 1]
```

I assume that the following statement performs in place change of the first element of the list.

```
    l[0] = 2
```

Since the variable a is referencing the same object,why it's value remains 0?  What happens internally in this assignment statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `l[0]` are two names for the same object, but when you say `l[0] = 2`, you are just redefining `l[0]`.  `a` still refers to the same object as it did before; it's just `l[0]` that has changed. `a` refers to an object, not a position.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you actually create three variables there `a`, `b`, and `l`. Only the last one is a list. What happened in line-by-line format was this:

```
a = 0
b = 1
l = [a, b] #which means l = [0, 1], not really the same referencing element a, b
```

Then if you check

```
a is l[0]
b is l[1]
```

Both return `true` because the value they have are the same, but again, the *values*, not the *references*

Then when you change:

```
l[0] = 2
```

Only value in `l[0]` changes, it does not affect `a`. Best is to check using good debugger tool like `PyCharm`. It shows you in the watch windows and inlines all the current values of the variables.

Comment: The terminology you're using seems... awkward to me. `a` and `b` are names that store references to the same objects as `l[0]` and `l[1]` respectively. Basically, `a` and `l[0]` both point to (reference) a single object with the value `0`, but `a` has no reference to `l[0]`, nor `l[0]` to `a`. When you assign to `l[0]`, it changes where `l[0]` is pointing; it doesn't matter what it used to point to, because that reference is being replaced.

Comment: I think "a is l[0]" returns true means that a and l[0] are bound to the same object(two references attached to the same object 0).When saying "l[0] = 2",l[0] references another object 2 but a still references 0.Now "a is l[0]" will return false.

Comment: @programforjoy not necessarily the same `object` so to speak... consider the case when you specify `a = 5` and then try `if a is 5:` it will enter the `if` block. `is` can be used to check literal value as well.

Comment: @programforjoy: Well, I'd describe it as "two references _to_ the same object `0`", not "_attached_ to". Using "attached" in that way makes me think the names `a` and `l[0]` belong to `0`, which is not at all the case. Internally, `0` "knows" how _many_ things reference it, but it doesn't know _which_ things reference it.

Comment: @Ian: No, it doesn't work like that. "Literal value" is not a meaningful concept here; Python doesn't differentiate between "primitives" and "high level types" the way a language like Java does. The small `int` cache is fooling you. CPython maintains a cache of all `ints` between, IIRC, -5 and 260 (maybe 256, have to double check). `is` is a direct pointer comparison; it only returns `True` when the names are bound to the same object.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ah, actually the way you distinguish between "reference to" and "attached to" also helps me to further understand...

Comment: @ShadowRanger O.o I have been fooled all the way long then... thanks for clarifying it to me (and to the OP of course)...

Comment: @Ian: It's a common source of confusion; I've seen that misapprehension with regard to `is` from a lot of people. Happens with both `int` and `str`; with `str`, any `str` literal (possibly only below a certain size, haven't checked details) is actually the same `str` thanks to interning of literal strings. So you can do `a = "abc"`, `b = "abc"`, and `a is b` is `True`. But if you _create_ the same `str` value without literals (and in a way that Python's peephole optimizer won't internally convert to a literal), say, `b = ''.join("abc")`, then `a is b` becomes `False`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see, so the key here is to understand what are cached by default by Python... All "literals" cached by `Python` refer to the same `object` and `Python` caches small int and small str (and maybe some others?). And anything which is declared with those cached (i.e. a = 1, a = 2, etc) will be `true` when they are compared to the values cached because they *really* refer to the same `object` in th cache.. Here the `is` comparison becomes confusing...

Comment: @Ian: The real key is to basically only use `is` when working with singletons like `None` and `NotImplemented` (where `is` is the best solution), or when object identity actually is important for some reason. A less common use for object identity is when you need to test for someone passing an argument vs. not passing the argument, but all values are legal (including `None`). You create a special sentinel object, `sentinel = object()`, define the function as `def func(opt=sentinel):`, and determine if an argument was passed by testing `if opt is sentinel:`. Otherwise, use `==` and `!=`.

Comment: In all other cases, it doesn't really matter than Python is caching, and you're better off just assuming no caches exist.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I get it. Thanks for the elaborated explanation... ;) I appreciate it, especially this day...

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is due to the initial assignment:

```
l = [a,b] = [0,1]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
t = [0, 1]
l = [a, b] = t
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
t = [0, 1]
a = t[0]
b = t[1]
l = t
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
l = [0, 1]
a = l[0]
b = l[1]
```

The rest follows from this.

Comment: That last example is not at all correct. It would work as the OP experienced due to the small `int` cache, but for numbers outside the range of the small `int` cache, the code from that final example would not produce make `a is l[0]` true. The other three examples are sorta correct (the order would differ, but the final references would all match up), but the last example is _very_ misleading.

Comment: You're being fooled by the small `int` cache. Try it with values 1000 and 2000. `a = 1000`, then `b = 2000`, then `l = [1000, 2000]`. I'll wait.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, you're right.  I didn't realize identical integers only held for small values.  Thanks for the info.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It's actually quite subtle.  If you do `a = 1000` followed by `b = 1000`, then `a is b` is `False`.  But if you do `a = 1000; b = 1000` on the same line, then `a is b` is `True`.  It seems there is some per-line caching going on.  It also explains why `1000 is 1000` is `True`.

Comment: Yup. There are some interesting bugs with regard to that sort of per-line constant folding that the CPython folks had to fix recently. Here's a fun one, still works in Python 3.5.1: `a = lambda: True; b = lambda: 1`. As you'd expect, `a()` returns `True`. But so does `b()`. It constant folded the two `lambda`s because the byte codes were identical, and the constant tables for each had values that all compared as equal to one another (`bool` is implemented as a subclass of `int`, where `True` has the value `1`, `False` has the value `0`). They tested equality rather than identity. Fun, right?

Comment: Of course, `1` and `True` are basically interchangable, being parent and subclass, it's mostly just the representation that differs. What was really nasty was `a = lambda: False; b = lambda: 0.0`. `a()` and `b()` both return `False`. There isn't even a common root class there, and if you need a `float`, and `bool` doesn't cut it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, that's pretty horrible.  The following also works in Python 3:  `a = lambda: True; b = lambda: 1.0`  It's interesting that this worked in Python 2 but was broken in Python 3.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Here's a nasty one:  `a = lambda: False; b = lambda: 0j`.  These both return `False` in Python 3.